# create Android .apk from a decompiled .apk

Tags: android

i decompiled an Android .apk file using dex2jar, grabbed the java source files using jd-gui "File > Save All Sources" and got a .zip file and the java files within.
I did exactly the steps in this "guide": http://a4apphack.com/security/sec-code/extract-android-apk-from-market-and-decompile-it-to-java-source.

Then i made some changes in a couple of the java files, now i am wondering how i can recreate an apk file.

Decompiling with apktool, backsmali and smali tools work with .smali files, but now i have .java files...

Comment: Develop your own software

Comment: Please explain why you are doing this. No-one will help unless your motives are good.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't. Converting Smali files to java isn't perfect and 99% of the time you won't get the exact code, therefore if there would be a way to recompile it, it most likely won't run and it would crash (depends on the complexity of the source code). If you want to modify an App (I am not recommending that. **Seriously, don't do that, without the explicit approval of the developer!**) you'll have to modify the smali files, and then you can recompile it with apktool like this:

```
apktool b <app name>
```

and then sign it:

```
java -jar SignApk.jar key.pem key.pk8 <app name>.apk <app name>_signed.apk
```